# When NFC reads the card, it opens the application by itself, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc, ndef, cardreader

When NFC reads the card, it opens the application by itself but I want to read NFC only when I open this application

```
 <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

nfc_tech_intent_filter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what change you are expecting here?

Comment: I don't know , only share code. My issue is when NFC reads the card, it opens application. I want to read NFC when user logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is don't put the `intent-filter` and tech-filter in the manifest, this is what is causing the NFC service to open your application when it reads a matching NFC card.

so remove from the manifest

```xml
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

Just use  `nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch` or even better `nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode` API's in your activities `onResume` (and the disabled methods in `onPause`) to read NFC cards when you App is already running and in the foreground

Comment: very thanks, this solution worked for me, when I removed intent filter and tech- filter  in the manifest so this trouble was solved by you, again very thanks.